# Flutter - dynamically add or remove form fields (dynamic form fields)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dynamic

Please help me out with a situation where I need to add dynamic form fields to flutter.

I've done exactly that in my web application by using a jQuery plugin similar to https://github.com/cozeit/czMore.

However, I now have to implement a similar strategy in flutter.

Below is how the form is looking like.

[image: My Form in the Mobile Application]

When I click on a button say "Add more" below the "Solution" text input, I want to duplicate the fileds above it (i.e from Equipment type, model, ..., Solution) (with their default values) and therefore allow the user to add more to the data.

Please unfortunately for me, at the time of searching `[pub.dev][3]`, I couldn't find any plugin that did the job.

Please, do you have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need a plugin for this you can simply declare a StatefulWidget and in it you can have a field `List<Widget> formFields;`

So whenever you need to add another field you just say `formField.add( TextField(...) )` and call setState

And when you are displaying the list you can use a ListView to iterate over the list and display all of the elements